# Struts2 client side validation without using action class

Tags: validation, struts2

Need to do client side validation in struts2  only using validation.xml but my beans are in bean class. validation.xml only supports action class based validation.

i need client side validation without using javascript or any validate method.

Comment: you must use javascript or jquery to validate from client side. struts validation is action class based only.

Comment: is there any issue will arise if i use bean with jpa in Action class???

Comment: better you use it with a bean class to continue.

Comment: in struts2, validation happens either by using validate() method inside Action class or by using the validator xml's. In both cases, anyway the validation is action class based.

Comment: you use javascript or jQuery to continue with your validations.

Answer (score 0):

Struts Validator Framework provides an easy-to-use mechanism for performing client-side validation.

For each validation routine defined in the validation-rules.xml file Struts provides an optional JavaScript code that can run on the client-side to perform the same validation that takes place on the server side.

LoginForm extends DynaValidatorForm

```
<form-bean name="LoginForm" type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm">
    <form-property name="userName" type="java.lang.String" />
    <form-property name="password" type="java.lang.String" />
</form-bean>
```

following validations are defined in the validation.xml file.

```
<form name="LoginForm">
    <field property="userName" depends="required">
        <arg key="LoginForm.userName"/>
    </field>
    <field property="password" depends="required,minlength">
        <arg0 key="LoginForm.password"/>
        <arg1 key="${var:minlength}" name="minlength" resource="false"/>
        <var>
            <var-name>minlength</var-name>
            <var-value>6</var-value>
        </var>
    </field>
</form>
```

To enable client-side validation you have to place the Struts HTML Tag Library's javascript tag in each jsp page for which you need to preform client-side validation.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JS Validation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <html:form action="/Login" onsubmit="validateLoginForm(this);">>
        <html:javascript formName="LoginForm" />
        User Name : <html:text name="LoginForm" property="userName" /> 

        Password  : <html:password name="LoginForm" property="password" /> 

        <html:submit value="Login" />
    </html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi Tijo, thanks for the reply but i think you are saying about struts1.. but my problem is on struts2 in struts one they used to have independent form bean, but in case of struts2 they didnt provided such independent form validation with xml..